# Regex MatchEvaluator in Parallel

Tags: .net, regex, parallel-processing, stdout, stdin

I have a `Regex.Replace Method (String, String, MatchEvaluator)` ([documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) that I'm using where the `MatchEvaluator` has to do some rather heavy lifting. The calls are being made to another library using `StandardInput` and `StandardOutput` redirection. The nature of the library is such that I have to open a `StandardInput` and then close it to get the data I want out of it via `StandardOutput`. Needless to say this is a rather intensive process.

However, I do have more threads on my system and was wondering if there was a way to get the `Regex` to run with parallelism. I can't seem to find any overload that will allow that and I can't seem too even conceptualize how that would work given the nature of `Regex`. I've thought about artificially breaking the string, but I worry that would result in a break at a spot that results in a change in the processing of the Regex as it does use some look-around (though not much).

Can anyone shed some light on how I might be able to parallelize this? It is a single very large document with multiple (hundreds) of matches that need to be replaced. The result is a single document with all the matched strings replaced by the output of the `MatchEvaluator` function.

Sample document:

```
Random characters from all over the alphabet that have no use to me in this context. Including =, &, ", ', &, etc. [StringToReplace] More stuff I can ignore. [OtherStringToReplace]. More characters including foreign languages.
```

I'm using the following `Regex`:

```
resultText = Regex.Replace(text, "(?<=\])[^\[\]]+(?=\[)", matchEval)
```

Comment: You could wrap your entire pattern in parentheses and use `Split`. Captured results will be returned in the resulting array (between the split parts). You could then identify the matched parts by simple counting, and process those parts in parallel I suppose.

Comment: Your actual pattern would be helpful here, to see whether it can be adapted to a solution like that.

Comment: But how would I rejoin the result sets? (Why not post your solution as an answer, so we can discuss there?)

Comment: If you provide your pattern and example input (or a simplified version - what's important is how you currently use capturing - if you do at all), I can try to put together an answer. You can simply rejoin the array, if you remove all sub-match captures from it.

Comment: This is a `Regex.Replace`, so I actually need to keep the original document with the replacements in place.

Comment: Do you have several strings to process in parallel or just one string that you want processed by multiple threads?

Comment: One string, multiple threads.

Comment: Only a comment but I would try breaking out the matchEval and sending it to a BlockingCollection.  So the regex (without the matchEval) is the producer and consumer is a parallel matchEval.  Use a max size of the collection to keep from spinning up too many threads.

Comment: @Blam, I can't quite understand what you are saying here. Can you illustrate with some pseudo-code?

Comment: First need to know more about the nature.  Do you get just one string out of the pure replace?  Or do you get multiple matches that are sent to the eval.  Can you re-factor to send multiple independent matches to eval?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose I want to get *words* from this input and do a costly operation on each of them like converting to uppercase :)

```
string input = @"abc 123 def 456 ghi 789 jkl mno pqr";
string pattern = @"[a-z]+";
```

What I would do is:

**1- Get all matches**

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(input,pattern).Cast<Match>().Select(m=>m.Value);
```

**2- Do the costly operation on all matches (parallel) and store the result in a dictionary**

```
var dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
Parallel.ForEach(matches, m =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000); // <--Time consuming OP.
    dict[m] = m.ToUpper();
});
```

**3- Do the replacement using the dictionary**

```
var output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, m => dict[m.Value]);
```

Comment: +1 Check for dict[m] first to avoid the costly operation.  With a producer consumer model might be able to avoid a second .Replace.    OP is not responsive so I am not inclined to test.

Comment: Since, in a given run of the application, the replacement calculation won't change, using a ConcurrentDictionary really speeds things up a lot. This was a very easy pattern to implement. Thanks!